# How can I write a SQL query that finds all entries in the database where a particular column occurs twice or more?

Tags: sql

I have a table called Laptop that has a column named "HD".  How can I write a query that will find all "HD" entries that occur twice or more?

[HD]
10
20
20
40
50
10

So, out of those entries in HD, the query will return 10, and 20 because they both occur twice or more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is surely a duplicate, but couldn't find it. Anyhow, you do it with the HAVING clause after an aggregate.

```
SELECT HD,COUNT(HD) FROM Laptop GROUP BY HD HAVING COUNT(HD) > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

SELECT HD, count(HD) FROM LAPTOP GROUP BY HD HAVING COUNT(HD) > 1

Comment: Why did you add the exact same answer (except the capitalization change in LAPTOP and count) 4 minutes later?

Comment: Sychroicity! There were no answers when I started typing, and, I delayed a little while I fired up sqlserver to check the "Having" sysntax was correct. It is after all THE correct answer so its not surprising two or more people came up with it.

Answer (score 0):

select HD from LapTop
  group by HD
  having count(*)>1